# .NET 8 Necessary Group Policy Permissions

Tags: c#, .net, group-policy

Running even a simple console application built on .NET 8 using an updated Visual Studio 2022 I'm getting group policy errors. I've contacted my system administrators, and they are asking for more details regarding proper setup for .Net 8 as we went through a similar process for .NET 6.

[image: Group Policy Error]

My googling has not turned up any documentation official or otherwise about what permissions are necessary for running projects in visual studio. The programs can be run from the folder using admin permissions but I don't think that's an acceptable workflow.

What permissions are required for me to run any Visual Studio solutions from say my \source\repos\ folder? Do those permissions change if I want to run programs from a shared drive?

Comment: .NET 8 doesn't require policy changes. A policy is explicitly blocking your application or rather, your attempt to use a debugger. [Debug Programs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/debug-programs) is a privilege given to local administrators by default. This means you aren't an administrator on your dev machine.  Try using the [Resultant Set of Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn265978(v=ws.11)) tool to see what changes were applied to your machine.

Comment: Can you run your program with `Ctrl+F5` ie without debugging, or from the command line? If you can, the problem is that you don't have the `Debug Programs` privilege

Comment: Checked and I do not have Debug Programs privilege, but running using Ctrl+F5 doesn't work either. I'll ask for the debug permission and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Can you run the executable from the command line at all?

Comment: I cannot. Working with our admin team it sounds like they've implemented a strict whitelist which is blocking execution of the programs. Currently trying to find a balance between least privilege policies and actually being able to perform our job.

Comment: If you can't even run the program you created, you can't do your job. Period. You can't even test if anything works or not. I guess, if you can install WSL on the machine you could run and debug in Linux. Or you could use containers to do the same. Visual Studio can [build, launch and debug programs in containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/?view=vs-2022), VS Code goes even further with [Dev Containers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/containers) and [Windows Dev Home](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-home/) brings all these together

Comment: This way, you could build, run and debug the program in an approved container